# String displays fine in html but becomes undefined in console when using console.log

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

I am running into an issue where i can retrieve a string and display it into a html page, but it is not possible for me to use it as a string in my typescript. Here are my codes.

TypeScript:

```
user: User = new User();
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
    console.log(this.user.email)
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item>
       <ion-label>Email: {{user.email}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

The intended email would display correctly in the html, but when using console.log to display the email in the browser's console, it is undefined.

So sorry for any inconvenience caused and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`this.authService.getCurrentUser()` is an asynchronous call, which means it takes some time and the next lines gets executed first. Therefore you are getting undefined in `console.log()`

To console the value, you may try like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(res => {
         this.user = res;
         console.log(this.user.email)
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be because this.authService.getCurrentUser() is async request, by the time your service call is resolved compiler is moved to next line.

You are getting in html is because after it resolved view is getting updated